# Asp.Net Application using MySql + Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, asp.net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

My question is simple: Why do I have to reference MySql.Data.Entity on my ASP.NET Application in order to work with MySql Entity Framework 5 in a class library?

I explain: I've structured a sample application in 2 layers: Asp.Net Web App and a Class Library (both in VB.NET)

I referenced MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity on the Class Library, where I created my Code First model and my DbContext.

I referenced MySql.Web on Asp.Net App and put the DbProviders on Web Config and connection strings.

When I try to run a simple query, it fails with a generic NullPointerException on MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory.get_MySqlDbProviderServicesInstance()

However, if i install MySql.Data.Entity on the Web App, then all goes as a bed of roses.

In my thoughts, if I'm separating the Data Access Layer from the Presentation, why do I have to reference a dll that is used only in the Data Layer? Is this in any way related to how CLR loads assemblies? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your class library references MySql Entity Framework 5 so yes, it will need to be installed. If you are developing locally, you can likely compile your application without first installing these bits (assuming your reference to your class library is to an already compiled DLL) but you won't be able to run your application.

Comment: Don't know if I got your answer right, but by question is not about deploying. Is what's the point to have separate layers if I have to place the Data dll's in the Presentation Layer too.